# css popup doesn't work on the last rows of table

Tags: jquery, html, css, popup, scrollbar

HI guys!

So I've a table in html. And one of the columns has a popup in the cell to show some information. the table is also quite large so I've added an horizontal scrollbar on the top and bottom of the page with jquery, with the help of @Stanley, see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934271/horizontal-scrollbar-on-top-and-bottom-of-table).

The popup always stays at the bottom of the cell. But the scrollbar hides the last ones.
So what I would like is the popup to stay above the scrollbar.

I tried put

```
z-index: 999; #popup hover 
z-index: 1; #scrollbar
```

but that doesn't work.
Anyone has any idea?

If any code is needed, just ask.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template, at the bottom:

```
 <div id="popup-flyer"></div>
```

Javascript file:

```
function make_tooltip () {
   var tooltip = $(this);
   var flyer = $("#popup-flyer");
   flyer.css('position', 'absolute');
   flyer.css('left', tooltip.position().left + 30);
   flyer.css('top', tooltip.position().top);
   flyer.append(tooltip.children('span').clone());
   flyer.show(1);
};

function hide_tooltip () {
   var tooltip = $(this);
   var flyer = $("#popup-flyer");
   flyer.hide(1);
   flyer.children('span').remove();
};

$(document).ready( function () {
$(".tooltip").hover(make_tooltip, hide_tooltip);
});
```

the css:

```
a class='tooltip'>
                <img src="image" alt="" height="20" width="20" />
                    <span> lalalakalsjsjhfksajhfdsh
                           text here....
                    </span>
            </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

use firefox firebug and position it using

```
 css  top:100px,left:100px.
```

can you increase width of table?
 actually i had a similar issue .
 i put an empty table with height of popup below the first table (you show popup on clicking of this tables columns).

So the popup will not hide, or go inside the scroll.

```
<table><tr><td>on click or mouse over show popup</td></tr>
<tr><td>on click or mouse over show popup</td></tr>
<tr><td>on click or mouse over show popup</td></tr>
<tr><td>as this the last td popup was going inside the scroll so i put table below</td></tr></table>

<table><tr><td height='50px'> </td></tr></table>
```

If this not at all your situation. pardon me  . :)

Comment: sorry I'm not sure if I understood you.. I show the popup on one column but each row has different information. So if I put an empty table with the side of the popup and underneath the scrollbar it will work? I tried put the values you gave on the popup hover but the popup disappear.

Comment: I think what zod is saying is just make sure there's a bit more room between the bottom of your table and the top of your scrollbar, i.e. by adding margin/padding to the bottom of your table

Comment: ok..but doing that I'm left with a blank space between the end of the table and the scrollbar. that wasn't exactly my idea. I want the scrollbar to be close to the table but on another hand I would like to be able the see the popup. In front of the table. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: yea i know.As there is scroll ,we cant define a common position (like center of the page) for popup. iddnt find other solution. If you find anything i can also implement . :)

Comment: perhaps in javascript something would do the trick.. I gone also try to find anything, if I find anything I post an answer with the solution. thank you :)