# Javascript horizontal scroll bar

Tags: javascript, textarea, scrollbar, html, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to create a horizontal scroll bar on the top of a textarea for an HTML form.  This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934271/horizontal-scrollbar-on-top-and-bottom-of-table), and StanleyH's example at http://jsfiddle.net/TBnqw/1/ works perfectly, but I have a further complication.

Can it be rewritten with a `<span>` instead of a `<div>`, and also as straight code without any jQuery?  The site I inherited has code that modifies all `<div>`'s, so I'd need to use a `<span>` in block mode if possible.

Answer:
Fixed for Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/TBnqw/537

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed for Firefox: jsfiddle.net/TBnqw/537

Answer (score 1):

In response to your first question, yes it can be done with `span`, the only thing I changed was `css` `display:block`, which is the main difference between `span` and a `div`, see demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/TBnqw/131/

**UPDATE**

[Non jQuery Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/TBnqw/200/)

Comment: This is using jQuery though. Can it be done without a framework or library?

Comment: I'm sure it can, let me see if i can add it to my answer later today.

Comment: Warning: onscroll does not work with Firefox. jQuery is probably emulating it with a timer checking differences in scrollLeft / scrollTop ...