# How add double scrollbar on a div

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a div class="table-wrapper" with table inside.  This div is scrollable (overflow-x) but the scrollbar is on the bottom . So I would like double scrollbar one on the top second one on the bottom to avoid scrolling down . If anyone knows how

Double scrollbar on the top and on the bottom

Comment: with some javascript, it could be possible... look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400738/how-to-create-two-scroll-bar-on-div-as-top-and-bottom