# how to set a TOP horizontal scroll only in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is the easiest way to put a top horizontal scroll on a div?

I found this solution but it must have both top and bottom scroll. I just want the top one.

[horizontal scrollbar on top and bottom of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934271/horizontal-scrollbar-on-top-and-bottom-of-table)

Comment: The solution would be identical to the one in the link you provided, except with `overflow: hidden` added to the CSS for `.wrapper2`. See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TBnqw/1436/

Comment: Please note that doing something like this may interfere with many accessibility tools and/or confuse amateur computer users.

Comment: Interesting idea. I bet you can build two DIVs with the same width and, using JavaScript, link the two on the x coordinate. Sliding the upper DIV with the horo slider will, onEvent, move the lower DIV (which would have to have a hidden overflow)... I don't have time to program it, but it would be interesting. I don't see how it would harm accessibility, I could be wrong. Definitely could be confusing though.

Comment: Here's an [onScroll event](http://help.dottoro.com/ljurkcpe.php) that might help with this idea.

Comment: @Jimmmy It's already done here (Just with that single modification from the linked answer in the OPs post): http://jsfiddle.net/TBnqw/1436

Comment: @ascii-lime :)... nice. I didn't see that. +1 to you

Comment: @Jimmmy Thanks haha. Feel free to write it out as an actual answer with explanation and such. I don't have the time right now so I just left it as a quick comment, but I'm hoping someone will turn it into an answer for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go... (answer "stolen" from @ascii-lime with permission :)

The solution would be identical to the one in the link you provided, except with overflow: hidden added to the CSS for .wrapper2.

```
$(function(){
    $(".wrapper1").scroll(function(){
    $(".wrapper2")
        .scrollLeft($(".wrapper1").scrollLeft());
});
$(".wrapper2").scroll(function(){
    $(".wrapper1")
        .scrollLeft($(".wrapper2").scrollLeft());
    });
});
```

Here's the updated css:

```
.wrapper1, .wrapper2{width: 300px; border: none 0px RED;
overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y:hidden;}
.wrapper1{height: 20px; }
.wrapper2{height: 200px; overflow: hidden;}
.div1 {width:1000px; height: 20px; }
.div2 {width:1000px; height: 200px; background-color: #88FF88;
overflow: auto;}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper1">
    <div class="div1">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper2">
    <div class="div2">
    aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb     cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </div>
</div>
```