# Is there a way I can add a scrollbar to an overflow-x <div> at the top instead of or as well as the bottom?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have

```
<div style="overflow-x: auto;">
   <table>
   ...
   ...
   </table>
</div>
```

This places a scroll bar at the bottom of my table. Is there a way that I could have this appear at the top of the table instead of or as well as the bottom ? Note that although I didn't use this I do have jQuery available if I need to use that. If anyone knows of the most well used jQuery scrollbar solution I would also like to know which to have a look at.

Note I'm using IE9 and above. Also I did see an answer out there but that's over 2 1/2 years old so I'm hoping some new way might have come up that I could use.

Comment: With CSS/ HTML you can't. You definitely need jQuery or something a like.

Comment: @LinkinTED - Thanks I thought it might need jQuery. I've not used that but it's available to me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3935190/1642219

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the scrollbar's position is determined by the browser which inherits it from the operation system. There's no way you can move that sidebar.

You **can** however create something that functions as a scrollbar!

- jQuery [Tiny scrollbar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/)
- jQuery [Custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)
- jQuery [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)
- jQuery [Nanoscroller](https://github.com/jamesflorentino/nanoScrollerJS/) (doesn't support horizontal scrolling)

There are a vast amount of plugins so there's absolutely no need to write your own.

Comment: I use "Custom content scroller", it works really well and has good browser support. easy to style too!

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done only with CSS and HTML....add JS and below is your answer : 
Source : [horizontal scrollbar on top and bottom of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934271/horizontal-scrollbar-on-top-and-bottom-of-table)
[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/nS74U/)
**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper1">
  <div class="div1"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper2">
  <div class="div2">
    <!-- Content Here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper1, .wrapper2 {
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}

.wrapper1 {height: 20px; }
.wrapper2 {height: 200px; }

.div1 {
  width:1000px;
  height: 20px;
}

.div2 {
  width:1000px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #88FF88;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
  $(".wrapper1").scroll(function(){
    $(".wrapper2").scrollLeft($(".wrapper1").scrollLeft());
  });
  $(".wrapper2").scroll(function(){
    $(".wrapper1").scrollLeft($(".wrapper2").scrollLeft());
  });
});
```

Comment: also remove the scroll from bottom in the fiddle.

Comment: @C-Link : Alan has clealy mentioned `I could have this appear at the top of the table instead of or as well as the bottom`....am i wrong in understanding something????

Comment: @UDB : yeah i know...added the link too....please see the edits before pointing out!! :)