# Scrollbar on top of DIV and nowrap container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nowrap

I'm familiar with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934271/horizontal-scrollbar-on-top-and-bottom-of-table) StackOverflow question & confirmed answer.

However, checking their [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/TBnqw/1/), I've noticed one thing I really really need. The container (aka div2 class element) doesn't have no-wrap property which I would really really need for my tables inside #container (nowrap for having tables in one row)

My code:

**CSS**:

```
.subnetTable {
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-table;
    border:1px solid #E8E8E9;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    white-space: normal;
}

#scroller_wrapper, #container_wrapper{
    width: 98%; border: none 0px RED;
    overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y:hidden;
}
#scroller_wrapper{height: 16px; }
#scroller { width: 500px; height: 16px; }
#container { width: 500px; overflow: auto;}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="scroller_wrapper">
    <div id="scroller">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container_wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <table class="subnetTable"><tr><td>12341234</td></tr></table>
<table class="subnetTable"><tr><td>12341234 123412341234 1234123412 34123412341 2341234123412 341234123 412341234</td></tr></table>
<table class="subnetTable"><tr><td>12341234</td></tr></table>
<table class="subnetTable"><tr><td>12341234   123412341 2341234123412 34123412341234 123412341 23412341234</td></tr></table>
<table class="subnetTable"><tr><td>12341234   1234123412 341234123412 34123412341234 123412341 23412341234</td></tr></table>
<table class="subnetTable"><tr><td>12341234   123412341 2341234123412 34123412341234 123412341 23412341234</td></tr></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT (jQuery)**:

```
// SCROLLBARS
$(function(){
  $("#scroller_wrapper").scroll(function(){
    $("#container_wrapper").scrollLeft($("#scroller_wrapper").scrollLeft());
  });
  $("#container_wrapper").scroll(function(){
    $("#scroller_wrapper").scrollLeft($("#container_wrapper").scrollLeft());
  });
});


// CONTAINER RESIZE
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#scroller').css('width', ($(window).width() - 10) );
    $('#container').css('width', ($(window).width() - 10) );
});
```

**MY JsFiddle Code & the Problem**:

[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/TBnqw/2096/).

The problem appears, when you add white-space: nowrap; to #container class. Instead of correct result, it creates another scrollbar at bottom which I wouldn't like. IT does move tables to one row but it doesn't create correct scrollbar at bottom or top anymore (replacing tables with only text doesn't work either).

Please help me out!

Comment: 1) Why are you using tables? DIVs or even an unordered list may be more semantic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With you code as-is the solution is to put a `<br>` just before the fourth table or wrapping the first three and second three tables in a block level element such as a div.

#### Why?

Each table is inline - so setting #container to not wrap will make all the inline tables extend out to the right. Adding a break will force it to break as expected.

#### Note

Please consider using DIVs or some other semantic element rather than tables - your code does not appear to be tabular data.