# Horizontal scrollbar for a page contains table

Tags: html, css, material-design-lite

[**JSFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/r8xn9aua/26/)

Here is my SSCCE, and in order to use the *HORIZONTAL* scrollbar, one needs to vertically scroll to the bottom of page/container so that the horizontal scrollbar becomes visible (i.e. it is scrolled into the viewport by vertical scrolling) and the user can use it.

I need the horizontal scrollbar to be FIXED, so that it is always visible, no matter what the position of the vertical scrollbar is.

**IMPORTANT:**

Now I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330745/how-can-i-make-the-horizontal-scrollbar-for-a-div-always-appear-fixed-on-the-bot#answer-11330931) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23206877/sticky-scrollbar-at-bottom-of-table#answer-23207363), but the thing is that I can not give a *fixed* height to `.tab-container`, because that gives VERTICAL scroll bar to the table (*inside* the margins-on-sides), but I need the Vertical scrollbar to be at the right edge of the *page* (and not at the right edge of the *table*), the way it currently is. That is the real challenge here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a perfectScrollbar for this. I've updated your fiddle.
JsFiddle is getting a little bit crazy with the code, but on localhost works well:

http://jsfiddle.net/r8xn9aua/32/

I think you might need to use position:absolute instead of position:fixed for the "ps-scrollbar-x-rail" positioning. Since it's a plain html element, you can do whatever you want.

```
.ps-container > .ps-scrollbar-x-rail {
    opacity: 1;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0 !important;
}
```