# How to get Scrollbar for left side of the Image/Div after it is scaled at the center

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I'm centering an image using `display:flex` & `justify-content:center`
and using some zoom buttons to scale the image when they're clicked.

The issue is that I'm not able to get a scroll bar to go to the Left Side of the image after it is scaled.

I checked about the scaling property and learned that it scales the (0,0) coordinates and possibly I'm trying to go the negative coordinates (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale()#scaling_the_x_and_y_dimensions_together)

Is there anything i can do to go to have full access of the image after it is being scaled? (by full access i mean to the left/right/top/bottom)
Here is the fiddle for reference : https://jsfiddle.net/r9sdhjyz/1/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand,  you want scroller to the left side .

Just add `direction: rtl;` in the styling of parent element like this

```
#parent{
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
  overflow:scroll;
  display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 direction:rtl;
}
```

Comment: That actually gives scroll for the left but removes the right side. I need full access to the img. i.e. TOP /LEFT /RIGHT /BOTTOM.

Comment: so you need scrollbar to all four sides? If yes, you can refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24804500/can-you-have-scrollbars-in-both-parallel-sides-of-a-div

Comment: I need scrollbar by which I access the whole image (the default horizontal and vertical scrollbars). As you can see, after it is being scaled, Some part of the Img goes out and remains inaccessible.

Comment: That certainly didn't helped. After img is scaled, the portion outside div remains inaccessible