# Activate scroll with click and drag with another element

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor, drag

How can I activate the scroll through another element by click and drag action. In my working fiddle is a horizontal scroll visible. But I want is to be scrolled through a click and drag action on **the top row**.
[image: scroll by click and drag with another element]

My question is how can this be accomplished?

`.`[Here is my working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justamir/fp2xgqL5/2/)

Comment: You want your scrollbar on top instead of bottom ?

Comment: No I want to scroll with the top instead of the bottom scrollbar. So the top should behave the same as a scroll.

Comment: So you want to simultate the horizontal scroll bar ?

Comment: A similar question was asked, here is the link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934271/horizontal-scrollbar-on-top-and-bottom-of-table

Comment: @JordanGoulet No this is not what I want. I do not want a scroll at the top, but I want to scroll with the upper element by click and drag action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library JQuery UI to [sort](http://jqueryui.com/sortable) and [drag&drop](http://jqueryui.com/droppable).
If the item is located exactly above the other, you need to add it to the item.