# Add Horizontal Scrollbar To TOP of Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, scrollbars

I am embedding a `gridview` inside of a `panel` like this, which works as it should, but I sometimes return a great deal of information and would like to be able to add a horizontal scroll bar to the top as well, can someone assist??

```
<asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server" ScrollBars="Both" style="overflow:scroll">
<asp:GridView ID="grid1" runat="server" Visible="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        ShowFooter="true" Width="16px" Height="120px" >/>
        <columns>

        </columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

**EDIT**
I am trying to use the option from the link you provided below, but my grid width is **way** to small.  I think I have it set properly in the syntax tho?

```
<div class="wrapper1">
    <div class="wrapper2">
        <asp:GridView ID="grid1" runat="server" Visible="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
            ShowFooter="true" Width="10000pxpx" Height="3000px" >/>
            <columns>

            </columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .wrapper1, .wrapper2{width: 300px; border: none 0px RED; overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y:hidden;}
    .wrapper1{height: 200px; }
    .wrapper2{height: 200px; }
    .div1 {width:10000px; height: 200px; }
    .div2 {width:10000px; height: 200px; background-color: #88FF88; overflow: auto;}
</style>
```

Also, adding in the extra `<div>` tag throws the grid further down on the page than what I need it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing your panel and go with a div instead.

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto;width:800px">
   GridView here
</div>
```

overflow-x:auto will produce a horizontal scrollbar only if the GridView's width is greater than 800px.

Comment: that adds a horizontal scrollbar to the bottom, how can I add one to the top as well?

Comment: Not so easy to do without a bit of extra coding...  Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934271/horizontal-scrollbar-on-top-and-bottom-of-table

Comment: trying to follow one of the options in your link, but grid width is not correct, can you take a look?

Comment: Try fixing your width definition, it's currently 1000pxpx

Comment: How did you go? Any luck?