# R DT Horizontal scroll bar at top of the table

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a wide and lengthy DT in shiny. By default I would like to show the horizontal scroll bar on top of the table. Is there a way to do this? My current DT definition looks like below:

```
DT::datatable(dt, rownames = FALSE,
                    filter = fbox,
                    style = "bootstrap",
                    options = list(
                      dom = dom,
                      scrollX = TRUE,
                      columnDefs = list(list(orderSequence = c('desc', 'asc'), targets = "_all")),
                      processing = FALSE,
                      pageLength = 500,
                      lengthMenu = list(c(500, 1000, 5000), c("500","1000","5000"))
                    ),
                    callback = DT::JS("$(window).unload(function() { table.state.clear(); })")
 ) %>% DT::formatStyle(., cn_cat,  color = "black", backgroundColor = "#dee6ea",fontWeight = "bold")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Flip Scrollbar for All DataTables in App**

You could add some css to flip the div containing the scrollbar/table and then flip back the table content, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35148632/8099834) answer:

```
.dataTables_scrollBody {
    transform:rotateX(180deg);
}
.dataTables_scrollBody table {
    transform:rotateX(180deg);
}
```

**Flip Scrollbar for Specific DataTable**

If you only want to flip the scroll bar on one table, you could select the specific table:

```
#flipped > .dataTables_wrapper.no-footer > .dataTables_scroll > .dataTables_scrollBody {
    transform:rotateX(180deg);
}
#flipped > .dataTables_wrapper.no-footer > .dataTables_scroll > .dataTables_scrollBody table{
    transform:rotateX(180deg);
}
```

**Example**
[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

css <- HTML(
    "#flipped > .dataTables_wrapper.no-footer > .dataTables_scroll > .dataTables_scrollBody {
        transform:rotateX(180deg);
    }
    #flipped > .dataTables_wrapper.no-footer > .dataTables_scroll > .dataTables_scrollBody table{
        transform:rotateX(180deg);
    }"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$style(css)),
    fluidRow(column(width = 6,
                    h4("Flipped Scrollbar"),
                    br(),
                    DT::dataTableOutput("flipped")
                    ),
             column(width = 6,
                    h4("Regular Scrollbar"),
                    br(),
                    DT::dataTableOutput("regular")
                    )
             )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$flipped <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(mtcars, rownames = FALSE,
                      options = list(
                          scrollX = TRUE
                      )
        )
    })
    output$regular <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(mtcars, rownames = FALSE,
                      options = list(
                          scrollX = TRUE
                      )
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi @HallieSwan I've tried this example on a couple of browsers and I dont get the scrollbar at the top

Comment: If you add the `Scroller` extension to DT, the CSS solution here appears to have some unintended side effects.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the Scrollbar on top using what @HallieSwam suggested, but looked into the source HTML code to understand what parts needed to be rotated.
What worked for me:

```
tags$head(tags$style(HTML( 
   "#Table1 .dataTables_scrollBody {transform:rotate(180deg);}
    #Table1 .dataTables_scrollHead {transform:rotate(180deg);}
    #Table1 .dataTables_scroll table {transform:rotate(180deg);}
   "
)))
```

`scrollBody` turns the whole table, including the scrolling bar, then `scrollHead` is required to align the scrolling bar with the header in the final table. Scroll table will turn just the content in the table, leaving the scrolling bar on top.