# Horizontal Scrollbar Always On Top Of DataTable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datatables

I have a webpage that displays a DataTable. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35147590/2893712) solution to make the horizontal scrollbar appear on top. (Example can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ospaL0c1/))

Here is the CSS that moves it to the top:

```
.dataTables_scrollBody {
    transform:rotateX(180deg);
}
.dataTables_scrollBody table {
    transform:rotateX(180deg);
}
```

However, is there a way to make the horizontal scrollbar always appear on top even if the user scrolls down?

Comment: To clarify: you want the scrollbar to always be in view?

Comment: @MichaelM. Yes that is correct.