# Horizontal scroller (fc-scroller-clip) from the bottom to the top of FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, scroller, fullcalendar-scheduler

Does it possible in timelineMonth to change the position of the horizontal scroller from the bottom to the top with some option as shown on the picture?
[image]

It is useful when we have to much resources and need to searching for the scroller somewhere from the bottom to move few days right.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3935190/5190589) might be helpful.

Comment: Yes, that's it!! Thanx. It's working for me. But now I try to make scrolling width auto, because in the new scrolling bar is not anough place to scroll.