# vaadin Position of horizontal scrollbar inside panel being scrolled

Tags: vaadin7

Let's say we have a horizontally scrolling panel, but the bottom of the panel as off the screen.  Thus, the scrollbar is positioned so far down that it is off the screen.  Note that I am not talking about the scrolling position ( controlled via the Scrollable interface, for instance ), but the position of the actual scrollbar used to do the scrolling itself.  Is there a way to do one or more of the following:

1. Position the scrollbar at the top AND bottom of the panel instead of
   just the bottom of the panel
2. Move the scrollbar from the bottom of the panel to the top of the panel
3. Make the scrollbar hover at bottom of browser window ( which will not be the bottom of the panel, as stated above )

Thanks.  Can be mildly irritating being forced to scroll to the bottom of a panel just to scroll it horizontally, because then you have to scroll up to see what ever data you wanted to see.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934271/horizontal-scrollbar-on-top-and-bottom-of-table

Comment: An interesting idea.  Not vaadin 7, so not ideal in my case.  The problem is that Vaadin does not have a native scroll listener, but Scrollable interface does have the setLeftScroll, getLeftScroll, and so on.  So if I had a listener, I could do what you suggest rather easily.  Still thinking about it, though.  Good idea, maybe I can use it.

Comment: tried a version of your idea, but did not work.  Vaadin has various ways to reference JavaScript, and I could not get any of those ways to work for a "scroll" jquery listener.  New priorities came up, and keeping two scrollbars in sync between two panels is not important enough for my boss to justify continued research, so for now I am tabling this issue.  Maybe someone will see this thread and give me a good solution, so keeping it open.