# Change the position of a scroll-bar from bottom to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to achieve that the scroll-bar is at the top when adding or making changes inside its area.

Is there any way to do this?

```css
#manageJobs {
  border: 1px solid #e6e8ed;
}

#manageJobs thead {
  display: block;
}

#manageJobs tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 403px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 nopadding">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-striped" id="manageJobs">
        <thead class="text-info text-capitalize">
          <th class="text-center thOne">Sr.No.</th>
          <th class="text-center thTwo">Job Id</th>
          <th class="text-center thThree">Score</th>
          <th class="text-center thFour">Actions</th>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="file in processJdFiles">
          <td class="text-center tdOne">{{ file.id }}</td>
          <td class="view-orphan text-center tdTwo tableCellOverFlow">
            <p>{{ file.attributes.name}}</p>
          </td>
          <td class="text-center tdThree">{{file.totalScore}}</td>
          <td class="text-center tdFour">
            <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="click to process this Job Description" ng-disabled="file.processed" data-ng-click="processJobDescription(file.attributes.name)">
              <i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="click to see orphan for this job description" ng-disabled="!file.processed"
    data-ng-click="getJobOrphans(file.attributes.name, file.attributes.companyName)">
              <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="click to delete this job description"
    data-ng-click="deleteJob(file.attributes.name)">
              <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
            <button  class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title= "click to track" ng-disabled="!file.processed" data-ng-click="moveToContext(file.attributes.name,file.attributes.companyName)">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-text-width" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
            <button  class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title= "Download" ng-disabled="!file.attributes.isDocumentTracked" data-ng-click="downloadtracker(file.attributes.name)">
              <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML code as well? Try top:0; with the CSS.

Comment: can you provide  your code on https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Ok I will provide the html code

Comment: @Mik3NLupdated the code

Comment: I have tried to use scrolltop property as well But it is always giving 0

Comment: Take a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934271/horizontal-scrollbar-on-top-and-bottom-of-table