# Django admin change list scrollbar at top and bottom

Tags: django

In my Django changelist there are lots of columns that means there is a scrollbar at the bottom of the list.  Is it possible to get a scrollbar to appear at the top so I don't need to scroll down

Thanks

Grant

Answer (score 1):

The penny dropped thanks to AlexandreS and this is what I did

I used this plugin: https://github.com/avianey/jqDoubleScroll

I coped the code to my js file: js/admin-help.js

In admin in the model class, I have this

```
class Media:
    js = (
        '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', # jquery
        'js/admin-help.js',       # project static folder
    )
```

Then collectstatic and it looks like it works, as I want too

Thanks

Grant

Comment: Where does this go? Admin.py or Models.py? How do you add it to the template?

Comment: admin.py then in js/admin-help.js I have the doubleScroll code

Answer (score 0):

This is something that you will have to change in your template.

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934271/horizontal-scrollbar-on-top-and-bottom-of-table) of how you can achieve this.

[How to override and extend basic Django admin templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583877/how-to-override-and-extend-basic-django-admin-templates)

**EDIT**: But I am not sure that you can change the template itself.

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2024 and with Django 5.0, I was able to use a shorter version of [great answer by mozman2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58878467/23559169)

```py
class SomeModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    ...
    class Media:
    js = (
        js = ("admin/js/sticky-scroll-bar.js",)
    )
```

Django imports jQuery anyway, so I didn't need to include another import.

In my experience, `jqDoubleScroll`'s [README](https://github.com/avianey/jqDoubleScroll/blob/master/README.md#usage) in "Usage" section is no longer correct: I had to add `$` as a nested function's argument, otherwise it wouldn't work and throw something like "$ is undefined" in the console.

```js
/* 
file "/static/admin/js/sticky-scroll-bar.js"

In the beginning of this file I put
the code of the vendor script found at 
https://github.com/avianey/jqDoubleScroll/blob/master/jquery.doubleScroll.js

I explain why I did this below.
*/

$(document).ready(function($) { // Note passing of $ as argument, otherwise the next line will cause error
   $('.results').doubleScroll({ resetOnWindowResize: true}); // just illustrating the passing of a custom option
});
```

Another thing is that I had to paste the lines that call `.doubleScroll()` directly into the [vendor script](https://github.com/avianey/jqDoubleScroll/blob/master/jquery.doubleScroll.js) I had downloaded (below all its code). The reason is that if you create your own module and import the vendor module, it won't work with Django because this `js` attribute of `Media` subclass is a simple list of strings, so there's no way to indicate that some JS script is a module.

If I really needed to import module(s) in my script, then (instead of adding `Media` class to the model) I could override a respective admin template and add `<script src="..." type="module">` to its head by simply adding a line to a respective block. No copying of the entire template is needed. See, for example, [this old SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29997719).

But for this particular question, I think it's better to just create one JS file and add two lines to the model.

Note that if you put your JS file(s) into `/static/admin/js/`, then you won't have to edit anything in `settings.py` (usually it already has the line `STATIC_ROOT = "static/"`.