# Django Horizontal Scroll on Top of Changelist

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have the same problem as depicted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58876832/django-admin-change-list-scrollbar-at-top-and-bottom) by mozman2:

"In my Django changelist there are lots of columns that means there is a scrollbar at the bottom of the list. Is it possible to get a scrollbar to appear at the top so I don't need to scroll down"

The solution from the given link seemed to help mozman2. However, I cannot reproduce it. Hence I tried copy-pasting the code from

https://github.com/avianey/jqDoubleScroll#readme

In particular, I copied this file from the repository to MyApp/static/admin/js/

jquery.doubleScroll.js

The file looks like this:

```
/*
 * @name DoubleScroll
 * @desc displays scroll bar on top and on the bottom of the div
 * @requires jQuery
 *
 * @author Pawel Suwala - http://suwala.eu/
 * @author Antoine Vianey - http://www.astek.fr/
 * @version 0.5 (11-11-2015)
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 * Usage:
 * https://github.com/avianey/jqDoubleScroll
 */
 (function( $ ) {

    jQuery.fn.doubleScroll = function(userOptions) {

        // Default options
        var options = {
            contentElement: undefined, // Widest element, if not specified first child element will be used
            scrollCss: {
                'overflow-x': 'auto',
                'overflow-y': 'hidden',
                'height': '20px'
            },
            contentCss: {
                'overflow-x': 'auto',
                'overflow-y': 'hidden'
            },
            onlyIfScroll: true, // top scrollbar is not shown if the bottom one is not present
            resetOnWindowResize: false, // recompute the top ScrollBar requirements when the window is resized
            timeToWaitForResize: 30 // wait for the last update event (usefull when browser fire resize event constantly during ressing)
        };

        $.extend(true, options, userOptions);

        // do not modify
        // internal stuff
        $.extend(options, {
            topScrollBarMarkup: '<div class="doubleScroll-scroll-wrapper"><div class="doubleScroll-scroll"></div></div>',
            topScrollBarWrapperSelector: '.doubleScroll-scroll-wrapper',
            topScrollBarInnerSelector: '.doubleScroll-scroll'
        });

        var _showScrollBar = function($self, options) {

            if (options.onlyIfScroll && $self.get(0).scrollWidth <= $self.width()) {
                // content doesn't scroll
                // remove any existing occurrence...
                $self.prev(options.topScrollBarWrapperSelector).remove();
                return;
            }

            // add div that will act as an upper scroll only if not already added to the DOM
            var $topScrollBar = $self.prev(options.topScrollBarWrapperSelector);

            if ($topScrollBar.length == 0) {

                // creating the scrollbar
                // added before in the DOM
                $topScrollBar = $(options.topScrollBarMarkup);
                $self.before($topScrollBar);

                // apply the css
                $topScrollBar.css(options.scrollCss);
                $(options.topScrollBarInnerSelector).css("height", "20px");
                $self.css(options.contentCss);

                var scrolling = false;

                // bind upper scroll to bottom scroll
                $topScrollBar.bind('scroll.doubleScroll', function() {
                    if (scrolling) {
                        scrolling = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    scrolling = true;
                    $self.scrollLeft($topScrollBar.scrollLeft());
                });

                // bind bottom scroll to upper scroll
                var selfScrollHandler = function() {
                    if (scrolling) {
                        scrolling = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    scrolling = true;
                    $topScrollBar.scrollLeft($self.scrollLeft());
                };
                $self.bind('scroll.doubleScroll', selfScrollHandler);
            }

            // find the content element (should be the widest one)
            var $contentElement;

            if (options.contentElement !== undefined && $self.find(options.contentElement).length !== 0) {
                $contentElement = $self.find(options.contentElement);
            } else {
                $contentElement = $self.find('>:first-child');
            }

            // set the width of the wrappers
            $(options.topScrollBarInnerSelector, $topScrollBar).width($contentElement.outerWidth());
            $topScrollBar.width($self.width());
            $topScrollBar.scrollLeft($self.scrollLeft());

        }

        return this.each(function() {

            var $self = $(this);

            _showScrollBar($self, options);

            // bind the resize handler
            // do it once
            if (options.resetOnWindowResize) {

                var id;
                var handler = function(e) {
                    _showScrollBar($self, options);
                };

                $(window).bind('resize.doubleScroll', function() {
                    // adding/removing/replacing the scrollbar might resize the window
                    // so the resizing flag will avoid the infinite loop here...
                    clearTimeout(id);
                    id = setTimeout(handler, options.timeToWaitForResize);
                });

            }

        });

    }

}( jQuery ));
```

I then told django about the file using

```
class Media:
    js = (
    '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', # jquery
    'js/jquery.doubleScroll.js',       # project static folder
)
```

Afterwards I followed with a collectstatic-command:

```
...

Copying '/MyApp/static/admin/js/jquery.doubleScroll.js'

...
1 static file copied to '/MyApp/static', 123 unmodified.
```

However, the horizontal scroll-bar on top doesn't show.

In the github repository it is suggested to use the double-scrollbar by

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.double-scroll').doubleScroll();
});
```

Where do I put this? I tried using it on the same .js-File instead of the starting

```
(function( $ ) {
...
};
```

This didn't help neither.

I guess I am missing out on something?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by knowing the syntax for django - jquery.
Here's how:

I got 2 new .js - Files, one which just calls the function of the double-scroll provided (calling.js) and the js-Files of the authors (doubleScroll.js) itself.

In your adminModel in admin.py you put in:

```
class Media:
    js = ('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js',
          'admin/js/doubleScroll.js',
          'admin/js/calling.js',)
```

The '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js' - link is necessary to make native jquery possible to run, if I understood correctly.

calling.js:

```
django.jQuery(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(() => $('.results').doubleScroll({resetOnWindowResize: true}), 245);
});
```

doubleScroll.js:

```
/*
 * @name DoubleScroll
 * @desc displays scroll bar on top and on the bottom of the div
 * @requires jQuery
 *
 * @author Pawel Suwala - http://suwala.eu/
 * @author Antoine Vianey - http://www.astek.fr/
 * @version 0.5 (11-11-2015)
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 * Usage:
 * https://github.com/avianey/jqDoubleScroll
 */
 (function( $ ) {

    jQuery.fn.doubleScroll = function(userOptions) {

        // Default options
        var options = {
            contentElement: undefined, // Widest element, if not specified first child element will be used
            scrollCss: {
                'overflow-x': 'auto',
                'overflow-y': 'hidden',
                'height': '20px'
            },
            contentCss: {
                'overflow-x': 'auto',
                'overflow-y': 'hidden'
            },
            onlyIfScroll: true, // top scrollbar is not shown if the bottom one is not present
            resetOnWindowResize: false, // recompute the top ScrollBar requirements when the window is resized
            timeToWaitForResize: 30 // wait for the last update event (usefull when browser fire resize event constantly during ressing)
        };

        $.extend(true, options, userOptions);

        // do not modify
        // internal stuff
        $.extend(options, {
            topScrollBarMarkup: '<div class="doubleScroll-scroll-wrapper"><div class="doubleScroll-scroll"></div></div>',
            topScrollBarWrapperSelector: '.doubleScroll-scroll-wrapper',
            topScrollBarInnerSelector: '.doubleScroll-scroll'
        });

        var _showScrollBar = function($self, options) {

            if (options.onlyIfScroll && $self.get(0).scrollWidth <= $self.width()) {
                // content doesn't scroll
                // remove any existing occurrence...
                $self.prev(options.topScrollBarWrapperSelector).remove();
                return;
            }

            // add div that will act as an upper scroll only if not already added to the DOM
            var $topScrollBar = $self.prev(options.topScrollBarWrapperSelector);

            if ($topScrollBar.length == 0) {

                // creating the scrollbar
                // added before in the DOM
                $topScrollBar = $(options.topScrollBarMarkup);
                $self.before($topScrollBar);

                // apply the css
                $topScrollBar.css(options.scrollCss);
                $(options.topScrollBarInnerSelector).css("height", "20px");
                $self.css(options.contentCss);

                var scrolling = false;

                // bind upper scroll to bottom scroll
                $topScrollBar.bind('scroll.doubleScroll', function() {
                    if (scrolling) {
                        scrolling = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    scrolling = true;
                    $self.scrollLeft($topScrollBar.scrollLeft());
                });

                // bind bottom scroll to upper scroll
                var selfScrollHandler = function() {
                    if (scrolling) {
                        scrolling = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    scrolling = true;
                    $topScrollBar.scrollLeft($self.scrollLeft());
                };
                $self.bind('scroll.doubleScroll', selfScrollHandler);
            }

            // find the content element (should be the widest one)
            var $contentElement;

            if (options.contentElement !== undefined && $self.find(options.contentElement).length !== 0) {
                $contentElement = $self.find(options.contentElement);
            } else {
                $contentElement = $self.find('>:first-child');
            }

            // set the width of the wrappers
            $(options.topScrollBarInnerSelector, $topScrollBar).width($contentElement.outerWidth());
            $topScrollBar.width($self.width());
            $topScrollBar.scrollLeft($self.scrollLeft());

        }

        return this.each(function() {

            var $self = $(this);

            _showScrollBar($self, options);

            // bind the resize handler
            // do it once
            if (options.resetOnWindowResize) {

                var id;
                var handler = function(e) {
                    _showScrollBar($self, options);
                };

                $(window).bind('resize.doubleScroll', function() {
                    // adding/removing/replacing the scrollbar might resize the window
                    // so the resizing flag will avoid the infinite loop here...
                    clearTimeout(id);
                    id = setTimeout(handler, options.timeToWaitForResize);
                });

            }

        });

    }

}( jQuery ));
```

Dont forget to run

```
collectstatic
```

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` is included in `Django`, so only one `.js` file is required.

### 1. admin.py

```py
# Created by BaiJiFeiLong@gmail.com at 2022/5/5
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = User

    class Media(object):
        js = (
            "js/doubleScroll.js",
        )
```

### 2. js/doubleScroll.js

```js
/*
 * @name DoubleScroll
 * @desc displays scroll bar on top and on the bottom of the div
 * @requires jQuery
 *
 * @author Pawel Suwala - http://suwala.eu/
 * @author Antoine Vianey - http://www.astek.fr/
 * @version 0.5 (11-11-2015)
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 * Usage:
 * https://github.com/avianey/jqDoubleScroll
 */
 (function( $ ) {

    jQuery.fn.doubleScroll = function(userOptions) {

        // Default options
        var options = {
            contentElement: undefined, // Widest element, if not specified first child element will be used
            scrollCss: {
                'overflow-x': 'auto',
                'overflow-y': 'hidden',
                'height': '20px'
            },
            contentCss: {
                'overflow-x': 'auto',
                'overflow-y': 'hidden'
            },
            onlyIfScroll: true, // top scrollbar is not shown if the bottom one is not present
            resetOnWindowResize: false, // recompute the top ScrollBar requirements when the window is resized
            timeToWaitForResize: 30 // wait for the last update event (usefull when browser fire resize event constantly during ressing)
        };

        $.extend(true, options, userOptions);

        // do not modify
        // internal stuff
        $.extend(options, {
            topScrollBarMarkup: '<div class="doubleScroll-scroll-wrapper"><div class="doubleScroll-scroll"></div></div>',
            topScrollBarWrapperSelector: '.doubleScroll-scroll-wrapper',
            topScrollBarInnerSelector: '.doubleScroll-scroll'
        });

        var _showScrollBar = function($self, options) {

            if (options.onlyIfScroll && $self.get(0).scrollWidth <= Math.round($self.width())) {
                // content doesn't scroll
                // remove any existing occurrence...
                $self.prev(options.topScrollBarWrapperSelector).remove();
                return;
            }

            // add div that will act as an upper scroll only if not already added to the DOM
            var $topScrollBar = $self.prev(options.topScrollBarWrapperSelector);

            if ($topScrollBar.length == 0) {

                // creating the scrollbar
                // added before in the DOM
                $topScrollBar = $(options.topScrollBarMarkup);
                $self.before($topScrollBar);

                // apply the css
                $topScrollBar.css(options.scrollCss);
                $(options.topScrollBarInnerSelector).css("height", "20px");
                $self.css(options.contentCss);

                var scrolling = false;

                // bind upper scroll to bottom scroll
                $topScrollBar.bind('scroll.doubleScroll', function() {
                    if (scrolling) {
                        scrolling = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    scrolling = true;
                    $self.scrollLeft($topScrollBar.scrollLeft());
                });

                // bind bottom scroll to upper scroll
                var selfScrollHandler = function() {
                    if (scrolling) {
                        scrolling = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    scrolling = true;
                    $topScrollBar.scrollLeft($self.scrollLeft());
                };
                $self.bind('scroll.doubleScroll', selfScrollHandler);
            }

            // find the content element (should be the widest one)
            var $contentElement;

            if (options.contentElement !== undefined && $self.find(options.contentElement).length !== 0) {
                $contentElement = $self.find(options.contentElement);
            } else {
                $contentElement = $self.find('>:first-child');
            }

            // set the width of the wrappers
            $(options.topScrollBarInnerSelector, $topScrollBar).width($contentElement.outerWidth());
            $topScrollBar.width($self.width());
            $topScrollBar.scrollLeft($self.scrollLeft());

        }

        return this.each(function() {

            var $self = $(this);

            _showScrollBar($self, options);

            // bind the resize handler
            // do it once
            if (options.resetOnWindowResize) {

                var id;
                var handler = function(e) {
                    _showScrollBar($self, options);
                };

                $(window).bind('resize.doubleScroll', function() {
                    // adding/removing/replacing the scrollbar might resize the window
                    // so the resizing flag will avoid the infinite loop here...
                    clearTimeout(id);
                    id = setTimeout(handler, options.timeToWaitForResize);
                });

            }

        });

    }

}( jQuery ));


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    django.jQuery('.results').doubleScroll({resetOnWindowResize: true});
})
```

### 3. Restart Django server

Maybe `python manage.py collectstatic` is required.

Press `F12` in your browser, make sure the `.js` file is loaded correctly.