# Fullcalendar scheduler, add scroller horizontal also under header

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Is there a way to "duplicate" the horizontal scroller in full calendar (scheduler mode) to show it also under the timeline header?

So having 2 horizontal scroller, one default at the end of calendar, and another one under the header (timeline)

UPDATE: thanks to @ADyson I get this result using doubleScroll plugin:

```
$(".fc-body").find('.fc-scroller').doubleScroll();
```

[image]

It works great but there is misalignement in the scheduler....

Comment: There's nothing in CSS or HTML which supports duplicated scrollbars natively. Therefore, by extension, fullCalendar can't do it directly either. Here's a generic answer for how to add a second scrollbar to an element: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934271/horizontal-scrollbar-on-top-and-bottom-of-table . I'm sure there are other techniques too if you google it. You could probably work out how to attach that to the elements generated by fullCalendar. Whether you implement that just with a bit of extra script added to your page, or using a full-on custom view, I'll leave to you.

Comment: @ADyson thanks you. I've followed your link and used doubleScroll plugin. All ok but I get disalignement (see pic on original post). I've used: $(".fc-body").find('.fc-scroller').doubleScroll(); ...there is a way to rerender fullcalendar correctly?

Comment: To correct that I suggest that you also add a gap (using an extra div, or some padding or something) of equivalent height to the scrollbar into the element which surrounds the list of resources. I don't think re-rendering would solve anything.

Comment: ok I solved adding scroller also for resources