# v-data-table - add a scroll bar to the top

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm using `Vuetify v1.5`, and I have a `v-data-table` which overflows horizontally. It has a scroll bar on its bottom, but it is not that convenient to scroll down the whole table to be able to scroll it horizontally. How do I add another scroll bar?

In other words, I want the table to act like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934271/horizontal-scrollbar-on-top-and-bottom-of-table), but I have trouble with appending this functionality to the `v-data-table` body.

Comment: please share [mcve] of your table