# How to have a scroll bar at top and bottom of angular md bootstrap table?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mdbootstrap

I have an angular MD bootstrap table where I want to have a horizontal scrollbar at the top and bottom of the table.

Following is the code,

```
<div layout="column" layout-align="center stretch" flex>
                <div layout="row" style="margin: 20px;">
                    <div flex></div>
                </div>
                <md-table-container flex>
                    <table md-progress="vm.searchTablePromise" md-table single>
                        <thead md-sticky
                               style="background-color:#00a9da;"
                               md-head md-order="vm.query.order">
                            <tr md-row>
                                <th style="color: white;" md-column md-order-by="name">
                                     Name
                                </th>
                                <th style="color: white;" md-column md-order-by="id">
                                     ID
                                </th>
                                <th style="color: white;" md-column md-order-by="ein">
                                    EIN
                                </th>
                                <th style="color: white;" md-column md-order-by="phNumber">
                                    Ph. Number
                                </th>
                                
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody md-body>
                            <tr md-row ng-repeat="item in vm.data">
                                <td md-cell>
                                    <div style="min-width: 200px;">{{item.name}}</div>
                                </td>
                                <td md-cell>
                                    {{item.id}}
                                </td>
                                <td md-cell>
                                    <div style="min-width: 80px;">{{item.ein}}</div>
                                </td>
                                <td md-cell>
                                    {{item.phNumber}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </md-table-container>
            </div>
```

Now, I have a horizontal scroll at the bottom, I also want to have it at the top.

This link provides a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934271/horizontal-scrollbar-on-top-and-bottom-of-table) but I don't want to have a JS related code for scrolling.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unforunately, there is no way without javascript to have both a scrollbar on top and at the bottom.

It is possible to have a scroll bar on top with css, but that is still only one scrollbar:

```
md-table-container{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    display: block;
    transform: rotate(180deg) scaleX(-1);
}
table{
    transform: rotate(180deg) scaleX(-1);
}
```

The only way to go is to use javascript. And the easiest way to implement it is to use the [jQuery Doublescroll plugin](https://github.com/avianey/jqDoubleScroll)

Download the file and include it as ds.js in your html. Here is a full example:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="ds.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#the-table').doubleScroll();
});

</script>
<div layout="column" layout-align="center stretch" style="width:100%; overflow:hidden" flex>
    <div layout="row" style="margin: 20px;">
        <div flex></div>
    </div>
    <md-table-container id="the-table" style="width:100%; overflow:scroll; display:block" flex>
        <table  style="width:100%" md-progress="vm.searchTablePromise" md-table single>
            <thead md-sticky
                   style="background-color:#00a9da;"
                   md-head md-order="vm.query.order">
                <tr md-row>
                    <th style="color: white;" md-column md-order-by="name">
                         Name
                    </th>
                    <th style="color: white;" md-column md-order-by="id">
                         ID
                    </th>
                    <th style="color: white;" md-column md-order-by="ein">
                        EIN
                    </th>
                    <th style="color: white;" md-column md-order-by="phNumber">
                        Ph. Number
                    </th>
                    
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody md-body>
                <tr md-row ng-repeat="item in vm.data">
                    <td md-cell>
                        <div style="min-width: 200px;">{{item.name}}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td md-cell>
                        {{item.id}}
                    </td>
                    <td md-cell>
                        <div style="min-width: 80px;">{{item.ein}}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td md-cell>
                        {{item.phNumber}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </md-table-container>
</div>
```