# scroll in top overflow

Tags: html, css

horizontal scrollbar on top and bottom of div

```
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-2">
  <div class="col-canvas">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
  </div>
<div class="col-4">
  <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

style

```
#canvas{
   background-color:red;
}
.col-canvas{
   overflow-y: hidden;

}
```

https://codepen.io/ruslan-fathullow/pen/qBYmmOo

[image]

Comment: *"scoll in top instead of bottom"* what does this mean ? I couldn't understand what you want to have.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934271/horizontal-scrollbar-on-top-and-bottom-of-table