# How to add horizontal scroll top tailwind css

Tags: html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css

```
<div class="w-[92vw] overflow-x-auto">
   <table>
   </table>
</div>
```

I want to have a scroll horizontally from top and bottom of the table. i have already accomplished the bottom scroll but i can't seem to add the scroll from the top horizontally. I have already tried using transfrom or putting another div but it doesnt work. I am currently working on this in vue 3 compositions api

Comment: You'll need to show your attempts that didn't work.  Unless you provide your actual code that others can recommend how to fix, we can only point to [accepted solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3935190/6225326) you've probably already looked at...

Comment: The general UX is horizontal scroll bars are at the bottom of the viewport. Why do you want to break it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.