# HTML div overflow horizontal scroll at the top of div without jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to show `horizontal` scroll bar of div at top of div via javascript or CSS without jquery. By default it comes at bottom.

I goggled for it but did not got any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [horizontal scrollbar on top and bottom of table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934271/horizontal-scrollbar-on-top-and-bottom-of-table)

Comment: Thanks.but I don't want to use jquery. updated my post also

Comment: Then go with Sameera's suggestion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsG5w/3/), it has scroll bars in top, This is based on [How can I get horizontal scrollbars at top and bottom of a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274627/how-can-i-get-horizontal-scrollbars-at-top-and-bottom-of-a-div)

Comment: Thanks. You Really hepled me a lot. but I am not able to upvote.

Comment: @Odessa Tx, i think u almost there.